# Laravel 8 interactive debug with Psy shell not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In Laravel 7.x, I used to debugging interactively by putting `eval(\Psy\sh());` in the code.
After upgrading to Laravel 8. it seems not working anymore.
Is there any other way to do interactive debugging in Laravel 8?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a proper solution. So, the issue is [here](https://github.com/Ventup-IT/symfony/blob/9593d4535ecb110aa1fbe1b198b59acfea456e6a/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php#L72). The new way of `artisan serve` way is to create a process and when you try to use `Psy` it creates a new process.

```
(standard input):198:  434 ??         0:11.07 /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
(standard input):406:80139 ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
(standard input):407:80214 ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
(standard input):419:79506 ttys000    0:13.80 nvim app/Http/Controllers/UsersController.php
(standard input):422:80288 ttys001    0:00.19 php artisan serve
(standard input):423:80292 ttys001    0:02.66 /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.1/bin/php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 /server.php
(standard input):424:80387 ttys001    0:00.00 (php)
(standard input):425:80436 ttys001    0:00.00 (php)
```

The last two PID are two of the Psy I tried to run.

You can see I forked `symfony` and I changed the value to `true`.
That will allow you again to work as before. To get out of the process, `CTRL+D`.

If the version is lower, you can check out this [one](https://github.com/Ventup-IT/process/releases/tag/v5.2.1)

However, be aware that this might be an issue in read-only environments.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem when running Laravel with `php artisan serve`. In the same terminal where I run the command, the PsySH breakpoint uses `eval(\Psy\sh());` always automatically closed.

The only solution I can find at this point after some trial and error is to run the request via the Laravel Tinker REPL with `php artisan tinker`. So in the CLI, you can make a request to the route you created with the following code:

```php
// The following '/foo' is the endpoint of the route you created
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create('/foo', 'get');

app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)->handle($request);
```

Then you can do interactive debugging using PsySH as usual.